# Does setting position to relative on a div takes it out of document flow?

Tags: css, css-position

Does just declaring `position:relative` on a div without specify position coordinates such as top,left etc takes it out of normal document ? Plz provide reasoning.

thanks
dkj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't. `relative` positioning doesn't affect the layout, the positioned element is still in its initial place *logically*, hence **the occupied space is reserved**.

But it could be displaced *visually* by `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` offsets/properties.

> **[9.3.1 Choosing a positioning scheme: 'position' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position)**
>
> **`relative`**   The box's position is calculated according to the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) (this is called the position in normal flow). Then
>   the box is offset relative to its normal position. When a box B is
>   relatively positioned, the position of the following box is calculated
>   as though B were not offset. [...]

Answer (score 0):

No:

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document.

via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning